# Flutter - Use Atom syntax hightlighting in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, atom-editor, flutter

I love the Atom syntax highlighting for working with Flutter. But I find myself more productive with IntelliJ due to the hot reload integrated in the UI. Is there a way I can bring the Atom syntax hightlighting into IntelliJ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the Atom editor dark theme with the Dart specific syntax highlighting?

Comment: Yep, I have the Dark theme but how do I get the syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the [Atom One Dark Intellij theme](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes) IntelliJ theme collection website [color-themes](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes).

In Intellij, do: File | Import Settings, and select *Atom One Dark.jar*. Import *Editor Colors* and *Editor Colors (schemes)*. The IDE will restart, and the theme will be automatically enabled. Here is a screenshot comparing Atom (left) and IntelliJ (right) running the *Atom One Dark* theme.

[image: IntelliJ Atom One Dark]

As you can see, some colors (e.g. static class fields) do not match. If you want to customize the theme to have a perfectly matching coloring, go to settings or preferences (File | Settings for Windows and Linux, IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences for macOS). Navigate to Editor | Colors & Fonts. Create a copy of the Atom Dark One theme, and then start customizing the colors as seen in the screenshot below.

[image: Customizing Atom One Dark theme in Intellij]

Addition: I've created a version of the theme with the changes required to match the Atom color style. Here is the [download link](https://github.com/raju-bitter/shared-files/blob/master/intellij/themes/Atom-Dark-One-for-Dart-settings.jar).

Comment: Great, have fun with IntelliJ and Flutter :)